# Difference between emacs and emacs --load ./init.el

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, init-file

I have the `init.el` file with following configuration:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("tromey" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(setq package-user-dir (expand-file-name "elpa-only-org-ai/" user-emacs-directory))
(package-initialize)

(use-package org-ai
  :ensure t
  :commands (org-ai-mode
             org-ai-global-mode)
  :init
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-ai-mode)
  (org-ai-global-mode))
```

As per the suggestion of the author [here](https://github.com/rksm/org-ai/issues/59#issuecomment-1627829980).

From the shell, when I run `emacs --load ./init.el`, the `org-ai-global-mode` key bindings work as intended. If I just run `emacs`, they don't. The `user-init-file` evaluates to the same `init.el` file. And running `emacs --debug-init` yields no message.

What am I missing to make this library key bindings work by default when calling `org-ai-global-mode`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package has a bug.  The mode isn't actually global, so when you enable it you do so buffer-locally (and even *that* quickly gets squashed by the major mode for the initial buffer being called, clobbering all buffer-local variables).

```
org-ai-global-mode is a variable defined in ‘org-ai.el’.

Its value is nil

Non-nil if Org-Ai-Global mode is enabled.
Use the command ‘org-ai-global-mode’ to change this variable.

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
```

Note that final "buffer-local" statement, which we would *never* expect to see for a purportedly "global" minor mode.

```el
(define-minor-mode org-ai-global-mode
  "Non `org-mode' specific minor mode for the OpenAI API."
        :init-value nil
        :lighter ""
        :diminish <==== this line is a bug
        :global t
        :keymap org-ai-global-mode-map
        :group 'org-ai)
```

I believe the author of this code got *very* confused and used a keyword designed for `use-package` by accident.  It's certainly not a valid keyword argument for `define-minor-mode`, and there's no value attached to it, so it messes up all of the remaining keyword behaviours, which are required (in this macro) to come in pairs.

I.e. this says `:diminish :global` as a pair, and the remainder (starting from non-keyword `t`) all get *evaluated* (harmlessly) as the mode's body:

```el
t
:keymap
org-ai-global-mode-map
:group
'org-ai
```

`org-ai-global-mode-map` is defined by that point, and the rest are just symbols, so no error occurs from evaluating that sequence.

(It's a bit confusing that the author hasn't noticed this themselves, tbh.)

---

*Original answer follows...*

A couple of noteworthy differences:

1. `--load` is processed later; the following events (among others) have already taken place:

   - your init file has been loaded
   - `default.el` has been loaded (if it exists)
   - `after-init-hook` has run
2. Your `init.el` file is being loaded twice (given that you've confirmed that `user-init-file` is the same file).

Maybe start by adding a `(message "<something>")` at both the beginning and end of the file, and confirming that you see both messages when you start Emacs (and that you see them twice when you use the `--load` argument).

(Given what `user-init-file` is telling you I would expect to see all messages, but it's good to verify assumptions.)

I don't know anything about `use-package` but maybe that's calling `(org-ai-global-mode)` before something important has happened the first time through?

Are the key sequences in question bound at all?  If so, what are they bound to?

n.b. Conflicts between minor mode keymaps for a given key sequence are determined by the order in which they were `load`ed; but loading something a second time doesn't modify its existing position in the sequence (see `(mapcar #'car minor-mode-map-alist)`), so that doesn't *seem* relevant at first glance.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I can't upvote answers. You are right that `init.el` is being loaded twice when I call `emacs --load ./init.el`. However, running `emacs --no-init-file --load ./init.el` prints the message only once (like running `emacs`) but it works just like running `emacs --load ./init.el`. Clearly there's something emacs is loading that is interfering with the library and I can't find what it is.

Comment: > Are the key sequences in question bound at all? If so, what are they bound to?

You can see this minor mode key bindings here: https://github.com/rksm/org-ai/blob/master/org-ai.el#L197-L227

Note that my `init.el` doesn't have anything else other than what I pasted in my question.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Accounts merged. Answer accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

In between posting this question and creating my account, I somehow lost access to the question. I can no longer edit it or post comments. :(

So adding here my answer to @phils' last comment:

> You said they don't "work as intended" and you didn't clarify what you meant by that. My question was: are those key sequences bound to something else (something you didn't expect), or are they not bound at all? What does C-h k report for them?

By work as intended, I meant that the key bindings work. For example, I can press C-c M-a s to trigger an open-ai call to summarize the selected text in the buffer. When I run `emacs` on the shell, I get the message "C-c M-a is undefined" as soon as I type it, without even having a chance to type the final `s`.  When I run `emacs --load ./init.el`, then typing C-c M-a s triggers the command `org-ai-summarize` properly.

Running `C-h k` when it works, returns:

> C-c M-a s runs the command org-ai-summarize (found in org-ai-global-mode-map), which is

Running `C-h k` when it doesn't, returns:

> C-c M-a is undefined

Comment: Try https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts (I'm not sure whether they'll permit it if you can't "verify that you own both accounts", but they can probably confirm that it all came from the same IP and make a judgement call).

Comment: Oh, and as you won't get pinged for my responses to your initial account: I've updated my answer with the explanation to your problem.

Comment: Please follow this up with the maintainer -- raise a bug report for them and link to the explanation here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm discovering more of emacs and orgmode with your answer as well. :) I asked to merge the accounts so I can hopefully accept it later.